# No Icons or menubars visible in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, command-line, 13.10, icons, menu

I'm unable to see any icons or menubars on my desktop. However, I am able to open up the file/folder explorer by inserting a USB, which opens up the explorer and let's me open applications and files [image]

However, some applications are visible without the menubar on top, i.e. I can't close them. Additionally, I cannot search for terminal- no results show up. I found terminal in my usr/share/app-install/desktop directory, but am unable to open it 
[image]

I also can't open it using CTRL+ALT+T. So far, I've been able to work and open some files, folders, and applications, but the lack of icons is problematic. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

This is Ubuntu 13.10

-Thanks for reading